# Why am I getting the same prediction, recall, and F1 score?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have been practicing some machine learning algorithms and data science techniques for the past couple of weeks, and I came across a problem that I cannot sort out. I have already searched for other similar SO questions, but did not find.

I have the following kernel with the Bank Note Authentication from UCI dataset, and I don't understand why I am getting the same score for the precision, recall, and F1 score. Am I doing something that should not be done?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bank_df = pd.read_csv("../input/bank-note-authentication-uci-data/BankNote_Authentication.csv")
bank_df.head()
bank_df.info() # No null values.
bank_df.describe() # Already scaled because the dataset was built
# using Wavelets.

# Splitting 'bank_df' in attributes and label.
y_train = bank_df["class"]
X_train = bank_df.drop("class", axis=1)

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

y_train_predictions = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)

print("Precision: {}".format(precision_score(y_train, y_train_predictions)))
print("Recall: {}".format(recall_score(y_train, y_train_predictions)))
print("F1 Score: {}".format(f1_score(y_train, y_train_predictions)))
// Result for all three: 0.9836065573770492
```

Comment: Mathematically this should happen if the # of false positives is equal to the # of false negatives, maybe you're in this special case?

Comment: Given your numbers, I'm guessing you have 120 true positives and 2 false negatives  and 2 false positives.